# (vite or rollup) build exoprt name will be change

Tags: rollup, vite

I want to try to use vite to package my component library, but I encounter a problem. After packaging, I will change the name of the variable exported from the file

this is `vite.config.js`:

```
import { defineConfig } from "vite";
import path from "path";
import { createVuePlugin } from "vite-plugin-vue2";
import pkg from "./package.json";
const inspector = require("inspector");
inspector.open("9292", "127.0.0.1");
const extensions = [".mjs", ".js", ".ts", ".jsx", ".tsx", ".json", ".vue"];

export default (/** if you want to use mode : { mode }*/) =>
  defineConfig({
    mode: "production",
    base: "./",
    plugins: [createVuePlugin()],
    resolve: {
      extensions,
      alias: [
        {
          find: `@gb/utils`,
          replacement: path.resolve(__dirname, "../../packages/utils/src"),
        },
      ],
    },
    css: {
      modules: {
        scopeBehaviour: "global",
      },
      preprocessorOptions: {
        less: {
          javascriptEnabled: true,
          charset: false,
        },
        scss: {
          charset: false,
        },
      },
    },
    build: {
      lib: {
        entry: path.resolve(__dirname, "src/index.js"),
        name: "index",
        formats: ["es"],
        fileName: () => `index.js`,
      },
      cssCodeSplit: true,
      outDir: "es",
      assetsDir: "style",
      watch: {},
      minify: "minify",
      rollupOptions: {
        output: {
          //   preserveModules: true,
          //   preserveModulesRoot: "src",
          //   assetFileNames: ({ name }) => {
          //     const { ext, dir, base } = path.parse(name);
          //     console.log(ext, dir, base);
          //     if (ext !== ".css") return "[name].[ext]";
          //     return path.join(dir, "style", 'style.css');
          //   },
          chunkFileNames: (chunkInfo) => {
            // console.log(chunkInfo);
            return "[name].js";
          },
          manualChunks: (id, { getModuleInfo, getModuleIds }) => {
            const filePath = path.parse(id);
            const dirPath = filePath.dir
              .replace(/.*\/src/, "")
              .replace("/", "");

            if ([".css", ".scss", ".less"].includes(filePath.ext)) {
              return `${dirPath}/style`;
            }
            if (/vue&type=template&lang/.test(filePath.name)) {
              const realName = filePath.name.replace(
                /\.vue\?vue\&type\=template\&lang/,
                ""
              );
              return `${dirPath}/${realName}`;
            }
            if (dirPath) {
              return `${dirPath}/${filePath.name}`;
            }
            return `${filePath.name}`;
          },
        },
        external: [
          ...Object.keys(pkg.devDependencies),
          /@gb\/utils.*/,
          /node_modules/,
        ],
      },
    },
  });
```

this is my code:

```
export default function (fileUrl = '') {
    let file = fileUrl.split('?')[0]
    let fileName = file.substring(file.lastIndexOf('/') + 1) || ''
    let suffixLastIndex = fileName.lastIndexOf('.')
    let name = fileName.substring(0, suffixLastIndex)
    let suffix = fileName.substring(suffixLastIndex + 1, fileName.length)
    return {
        name,
        suffix
    }
}
```

when i build, the export name will be a,b,c...z:

```
function getUrlToFileSuffix(fileUrl = "") {
  let file = fileUrl.split("?")[0];
  let fileName = file.substring(file.lastIndexOf("/") + 1) || "";
  let suffixLastIndex = fileName.lastIndexOf(".");
  let name = fileName.substring(0, suffixLastIndex);
  let suffix = fileName.substring(suffixLastIndex + 1, fileName.length);
  return {
    name,
    suffix
  };
}
export { getUrlToFileSuffix as g };
```

I need correct name
some people know how to set config?
Thanks so much!

Answer (score 1):

set `output.minifyInternalExports = false`